# Double click to edit element in Meteor app

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

I am making a school project in `Meteor.js` for a hospital - the prototype of the app is up on http://lrh.meteor.com . In the view doctors section in the table, I want to double click on the record and be able to edit the `Name` and the `email id`, but along with this I also want to update in record in `MongoDB` collection. Any ideas about how I can implement this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this can help you.

Lets create this helper.

```
Template.example.helpers({
   'editValue' : function(){
    return Session.get("TargetValue" + this._id);
  }
})
```

And this 2 events.

```
 Template.example.events({
      'dbclick #spanIdOnDom' : function(e,t){
      return Session.set("TargetValue" + t.data._id,true)//hide the span and we set the input 
     },
   'click #buttonToSaveNewValue': function(e, t) { 
     //here you can take the emailId and the name based on this._id like this Collection.find({_id:this._id}).fetch(); and do the updates you want to do
     var newValueFromInput = document.getElementById('newValueFromInput').value;
       var idCurrentDocument = this._id;
       var Bebida = Collection.findOne(t.data._id);
       Collection.update({_id: idCurrentDocument}, {$set:{fieldToUpdate:   newValueFromInput}});
       return Session.set("TargetValue" + t.data._id,false); //we hide the input and we put the span again
      }
    })
```

**HTML**

```
 <template name="example">
    {{#each collectionFind}}
        {{#if editValue}}
            <input type="text" id="newValueFromInput"  value="{{currentValue}} " />
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="buttonToSaveNewValue" type="submit">Save new Value</button>
          {{else}}
               <td>
            <p>
              <span class="content col-md-10" id="spanIdOnDom" ><h4>Descripcion Bebida:</h4><br>{{currentValue}} </span>
            </p>
              </td> 
            {{/if}} 
    {{/each}}
  </template>
```

Of course you need to set your `Allow/deny` Permission and `publish/subscribe` methods to make it work more efficient.

**How it works?**

in resume you have an `<span>` tag with the current value, when you `dobleClick` on the `<span>` tag , we set the Session to true, the `<span>` tag go away and a new `<input>` appears with a new button then we take the value from the `<input>` and she update `($set)` into the collection, and its done.

**NOTE:** this is a mini-repo from [Simple Crud app in Meteor from Raj Anand](http://rajanand02.github.io/articles/Simple-crud-app-in-meteor/), but the code on the blogs is on coffee and i don't use coffee Script.

Comment: Thanks, I made it work. I think `t.data._id` is deperacated in 1.0 